# Undefined array key "password" in LoginController

Tags: php, laravel-9

If I click on the login button, it will display.

> Undefined array key "password."

I have searched here for this error, but the one I saw isn't working for me, so I thought maybe it's because I am using Laravel (9.2.0)

**LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
        $data = array(
            'cus_pword' => $request->password,
            'cus_email' => $request->email,
        );

        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($data)) {
            return redirect()->route('customers')
                ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        } else {
            echo "no";
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('cus_login') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" 
           class="is-invalid " autocomplete="email" autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" class=" is-invalid" 
           placeholder="Password" autocomplete="password">
</form>
```

Comment: `Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($data)` is expecting an array with a username and password. You're passing in `cus_pword` and `cus_email`, which it doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you access request params like, `$request->input('password');` ? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value. I am wrong; in v9. you can access them directly like that - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input-via-dynamic-properties

Comment: @waterloomatt , i guess it's accessing it because, if i input an email that is not in the database, it will echo no

Comment: @aynber this is the full error message                                                            ErrorException

Undefined array key "password"

Comment: The error messages usually have a file and line number. But as I've already mentioned, `attempt()` is looking for array keys `password` and usually either `username` or `email`, unless you've overridden the attempt function. You're passing in `cus_pword` and `cus_email`.

Comment: @aynber so how do I go about it?

Comment: Change `cus_pword` and `cus_email` to `password` and `email`

Comment: @aynber the cus_email and cus_pword is coming from the database, and it's displaying  error unknown column email and password

Comment: Please try what aynber has suggested and report back. Also, read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users and notice the name of the array _keys_ being passed to the attempt method.

Comment: @waterloot  i have changed it to email and password , i even changed it in the database but its still showing the same error,         undefined array key password